# if it wasn't for or if it weren't for?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

I don't know what should to write with I would think you were bluffing if it, should it be wasn't or weren't for?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please give the *full* sentence - *and context* - you are trying to write. What do you mean by "write with I would think you were bluffing"?

Comment: _I would think you were bluffing if it {weren't/wasn't} for ..._ is my guess. Either will work, both are common. Using "weren't" is a more archaic strategy and can be confusing, as you note.

Comment: I am marking this as a duplicate as a courtesy, but really the question as stated is utterly incomprehensible. I can't tell where one thing ends and the next one begins. Some formatting or at least basic punctuation would be nice. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

"If it was not for", indicative, implies a certitude.

"Napoléon was certain to win at Waterloo, if it wasn't not for unexpected heavy rains and his canons stuck in the mud".

"If it were not for", subjunctive, express a doubt.

"Napoléon could have won at Waterloo, if it weren't for his stubbornness to attack, despite unfavourable (US unfavorable) conditions and the opinion of his generals"

Comment: What is your basis for this answer? Please support it by links to appropriate references.